# Difference between video mosaicing and video stitching

Tags: computer-vision, video-processing, video-compression, stitching

What is the difference between video mosaicing and video stitching ,is this both are similar or is there any methodology difference?

Comment: I second that. There are, at least, two Wikipedia article on the subject, not xounting other websites.

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE. Can you put your reference from where you got the terms or their definitions of these terms? Where you are referring them from. I think it is trivial to explain the difference - but I am doubting my self if I have take the right context. At StackExchange, it is expected that when you have the question, you do your own primary research to find the answer and then put the full context that makes answers crisp and valuable.